# Repeatable superior letters "a" "b"... at the place of footnote, what do they mean?

Tags: superscripts

I'm reading a book(ISBN:978-0942299519) where there are occasionally superscript of lower case letters at the place of footnote indices. It appears they:

1) run parallel with footnote

2) are repeatable(there can be two a's)

3) don't usually go beyond "e"

I checked the original French text and there's no superscript in it whatsoever.

What do they mean?

Answer: They are translator's notes

Text:
[image: English text]
Note section of the English text 
[image: Note section of the English text]
Original French text
[image: original French text]

Comment: The simple answer would be: this is explained earlier in the book.  If that is not the case, include that information in the question.

Comment: I went through the translator's preface but it's not mentioned, however I did find, at the end of the book, a "translator's notes" section, which goes by "a","b","c"...

Comment: @Isaac - So did that section explain them?  Absent that, it occurs to me that the second "a" might be to indicate that it refers to the same thing as the first "a" -- that "them" refers to "attributes".  This might be something that a translator would do to assure that the original meaning was conveyed.